# Keyboard not working with HDMI

Tags: hdmi, display

I am trying to connect keyboard on my raspberry pi alongwith hdmi. But when i connect keyboard to the rpi, hdmi stops working and vice versa. But they both are working alone but not together. Any ideas how i can make them both work together.

This is my config.txt file and these are my current configuration for running hdmi on rpi.

```
# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1
# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
**disable_overscan=0**
# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16
# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720
# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=16
# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
hdmi_drive=2
# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
config_hdmi_boost=4
# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2
#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800
```

any thing i am doing wrong?? Any help would be appreciated.

Tejvir Singh

Comment: Sorry for wrong heading. Its keyboard not working with hdmi..

Comment: POwer problems. Your keyboard is sucking to much juice and killing the HDMI. Because HDMI also uses power to run. Generally, anything that breaks on the Pi us because of power. ;(

Comment: But i am providing it 5V supply from a adapter.. what else can i try??

Comment: Volts not not provide juice "Amps". BUt you might even use a 2Amp power supply but because the older Pi's uses these weird fuses it might still cause problems. Best bet is power power directly on GPIO 5vcc, as this feeds the USB and HDMI directly without any fuses(which is good here but can be bad for other things)  How much juice "Amps" has your 5V USB thing-a-ma-jig have?

Comment: This means we can give power directly to the 5VCC gpio???

Comment: Eureka! :) Yes. But it is `unprotected` - Which has it dangers. NO short circuit protection, no overload protection and generally just, mostly unrestricted. How much AMP's you giving it???

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1618/894

Comment: Not sure but maybe 1.5 AMPS...

Comment: The comments above are true in general, but the current rating of the PSU is not the total answer. You really need to measure voltage. NOTE many high current chargers for newer phones DO NOT supply a high enough voltage - because they comply with the new standard for chargers which only requires 3.6v

Answer (score 2):

Similar to my problem:
[Will not boot, black screen only](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7009/will-not-boot-black-screen-only/12954#12954)

90% of all problems are power supply.

Try a bigger current one - some of the stock PSUs don't have enough current. I used a Nexus 7 PSU - it is 2A works fine - but a reinstall of NOOBS fixed it.

Comment: Okay.. I'll try using a power supply with 2 AMPs.. And i'll post the results..